# Install Google Play Service 9.6 in Android Studio

Tags: android, google-play-services, updates, android-studio-2.2

i've got a problem with my google play service under Android Studio 2.2 in its emulator. I downloaded every update and installed it but my google play service is still version 9.4. It wont work to install the play service via drag-and-drop and its original apk-file. Can anyone help me out with this? I need to work with GoogleAPI and it tells me my version is out of date.

Thanks in advance,
J. Doe ;)

Comment: They release an update to play services but it may take a while to update the emulator. Meanwhile you can use Genymotion or a real device.

Answer (score 0):

You can update it by following the steps provided in this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html). This guide also shows you a sample screenshot for you to understand more the steps.

Here are the lists of lessons that you can learn with this:

- How to Update Your IDE and Change Channels
- How to Update Your Tools with the SDK Manager
- How to Edit or add SDK tool sites
- Auto-download missing packages with Gradle

For more information, check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28530586/google-play-services-version-for-android-studio?rq=1).